# Word correction help

Tags: translation, word-usage

> 意図は、毎日語学の仕事していますから、たぶん全体的に語学力よくなる。

I want to say something like "my intended meaning was that since I will work with languages, it may improve my general language ability."

Does this make sense? Are 意図 and 全体的に語学力 used correctly?

Comment: As a native speaker of English I'm not sure I understand your English or at a minimum it seems greatly convoluted "my intended meaning was that since ..."

Comment: As a learner of Japanese, I would also say that I don't think the sentence captures what the English states. (Also, the politeness is uneven: 〜ますから vs. なる)

Answer (score 2):

The short answer for your usage questions is:

意図{いと｝は、: doesn't make sense.

全｛ぜん｝体｛たい｝的｛てき｝に語｛ご｝学｛がく｝力{りょく}: makes sense.

My answer depends on the context of your sentence. Stand alone text vs. a larger body of text.

---

1.私が言いたいのは、毎日語学の仕事をしているから、全体的に語学力があがるでしょう。

Sentence #1 would make more sense with 「意図は、」or 「私が言いたいのは、」if your sentence was accompanied by a larger body of text. If you simply have 「意図は、」at the start of a sentence with no accompanying text the reader will question what 'intention' you are talking about.

※ Also instead of using たぶん, which is more of a spoken word, I would suggest using おそらく accompanied with でしょう to provide the same sense of doubt you're expressing with たぶん while being more correct and polite. (As mentioned in other answers: volitional form)

---

2.毎日語学の仕事をする意図は、語学力が全体的によくなる可｛か｝能｛のう｝性｛せい｝があるからです。

Sentence #2 makes more sense as a stand alone sentence versus being included in a larger body of text.  In this example 'intention' is moved to the rear of the first part of the sentence letting the reader understand the context of your 意図・'intention'　more clearly. Kind of like what I mentioned above in regards to starting the sentence with 意図 except in reverse it makes sense.

---

Notes:

意図　ー　本当の意味、本当の目的とする所、等

意図's meaning is closely tied into that of 意味.

Comment: I'm a bit confused because your answer is quite different than 変幻出没, but I think I get the general idea, although both of your answers are quite different, I suppose there is some subjectivity involved.

Comment: @PaulCunningham I live in Japan and speak Japanese on a day to day basis and never learned formally at a big college.  Text book Japanese isn't my strongest suit and everyone has different takes on a language which is why I think that 変幻出没's answer is also valuable. I would say his/her answer is the same as mine, however the wording is more vague in a culturally Japanese way (My opinion). 

Also its always a good idea to **NOT** mix forms formal/writing/casual/etc.  So pick the best fit and make everything match.

Comment: 「私が言いたいのは～(What I want to say is that...)」や「言いたかったのは～(What I wanted to say is that...)」から始めたら「～ということです。」で締めないと・・・

Answer (score 0):

I think that even though you might be understood it is quite likely that you won't.

意図 refere to what you're trying to achieve, what you have in mind to do. Therefore, it's related to an action. I don't think that you can use it to talk about “your intented meaning”. I think that 言いたいこと is much more faithful to what you want to say.

語学力 would describe your “power” in linguistics, if you want to talk about your ability to pick up a language 言語力 might have worked better but it already refers to the ability of being able to *effectively* communicate your thoughts using a language.

Last point, たぶん is often used in conjunction with the “volitional” ending (volitional is clearly not the best name but I don't know any other alternatives) to soften the assumption, if used without the volitional ending you state that your almost sure of what you describe.

Summarizing all I said, I would have said the following:

> 言いたいことは、語学に関する仕事をしているから、たぶん言語のすべてが理解しやすくなるのでしょうか。

I rephrased 全体的に because, here 言語が全体的に理解しやすくなる feels like you're refering only to one language and not all of them. 言語が全体的に理解しやすくなる would mean “the overall understanding of this language would become easier.”

Very last, 仕事をしている means that you're employed and that you're doing this job. If you want to let the “will” interpretation possible (like suggested in your translation) remove the ている part.

Comment: 私の辞書は不正確と思います。今からhttp://ejje.weblio.jp/ つかいます。

Comment: I find Japanese-English dictionaries misleading because often the scope of English words is broader than the word in Japanese, so I think that it is a good practice to look up the words you've found from a JP-EN dictionary into a Japanese dictionary to be sure you've understood the meaning the right way.

Comment: けっこう難しいです。ConstantFunさんの文章はもっとかんたんと思う。今語学に関する仕事をしているけど、英語の関係です。だから、私は日本語の語学を勉強しなければなりません。

Comment: If you could tell me what you find difficult to understand/intricated I would appreciate so I can make change to my answer accordingly.

Comment: I thought your answer was good and I think both your answers were helpful, just a complicated topic in general. Thanks!